# Error handling on createWriteStream

Tags: node.js

I'm implementing file upload with Node.js and my code works fine with normal case.

However, when I made it fail to write a file (for example, writing it to non-existing directory), it calls error handler, `fstream.on('error', ...)`, but it gets stuck and never proceed.

I was assuming that by unpiping the incoming stream, `busboy` moves on to the next part of processing, but it seems like it was not the case.

I'd like to run same `busboy.on('end')` to respond to the browser (with some error info), but how can I get this called?

```
var express = require("express");
var Busboy = require('busboy');
var fs = require('fs');
var upload = require('./upload');
var Path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.get("/", function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { Connection: 'close'});
    response.end('<html><body>' +
        '<form action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' +
        ' <input type="file" name="filefield">' +
        ' <input type="submit">' +
        '</body></html>');
});

app.post("/upload", function(request, response) {
    // request.files will contain the uploaded file(s),
    // keyed by the input name (in this case, "file")
    console.log(request.body);

    var fileId = upload.generateId();

    var busboy = new Busboy({headers: request.headers});
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        var path = Path.join('images', fileId);
        console.log('hello');
        var fstream = fs.createWriteStream(path);
        fstream.on('end', function() {
            console.log("EOF");
        });
        fstream.on('close', function() {
            console.log("CLOSE");
        });
        fstream.on('error', function(err) {
            console.log("ERROR:" + err);
            file.unpipe();
            fstream.end();
        });
        fstream.on('finish', function() {
            console.log('onFinish');
        })
        file.on('end', function() {
            console.log('file end');
        });
        file.pipe(fstream);
    });
    busboy.on('end', function() {
        console.log('busboy end');
        response.json({id:fileId});
    });
    request.pipe(busboy);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 9):

I solved the issue by placing `file.read()` in `'error'` event handler.

```
fstream.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log("ERROR:" + err);
  file.read();
});
```

When `createWriteStream` had an error, `error` handler is called and pipe connection is broken up (`unpiped`), but incoming stream (`file`) has unread data in the stream and that hasn't consumed.

By calling `.read()`, it is read (but not delivered to Writable stream because no one is listening to) and `end` event is emit to the reader.  This triggers `busboy.on('end')`.

Comment: I think `file.resume()` should be used instead of `file.read()`.